# move text to top in product view page using view.phtml code

Tags: magento-1.9, css, phtml, view

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-arjun.html)

search for "**Rs 10 Delivery**" displaying in bottom of the page. i want to move this text on top of the page using phtml.

you can see "**ADD TO CART**" button, above that button I want to display the text "Rs 10 Delivery".

Means in single line, i want to display "**Selling Price + Rs 10 Delivery**"

we are using following code in view.phtml

**part 1:    price.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>

<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying product price in different places (products grid, product view page etc)
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
 */
?>
<?php
$_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
$_weeeHelper = $this->helper('weee');
$_taxHelper = $this->helper('tax');
/* @var $_coreHelper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */
/* @var $_weeeHelper Mage_Weee_Helper_Data */
/* @var $_taxHelper Mage_Tax_Helper_Data */

$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_id = $_product->getId();
$_weeeSeparator = '';
$_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
$_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
$_minimalPriceValue = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_minimalPriceValue));
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
$helperSettings = Mage::helper('em0113settings');
?>

<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getAmountForDisplay($_product); ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAttributes = $_weeeHelper->getProductWeeeAttributesForRenderer($_product, null, null, null, true); ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_weeeTaxAmount; ?>
    <?php if ($_weeeHelper->isTaxable()): ?>
        <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_weeeHelper->getAmountInclTaxes($_weeeTaxAttributes); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_weeeTaxAmount)); ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes)); ?>

    <div class="price-box">
    <?php $_convertedPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getPrice())); ?>
    <?php $_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice); ?>
    <?php $_regularPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice, $_simplePricesTax); ?>
    <?php $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice) ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice, true) ?>
    <?php $_weeeDisplayType = $_weeeHelper->getPriceDisplayType(); ?>
    <?php if ($_finalPrice >= $_price): ?>
        <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
            <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="highPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="highPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="highPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                    <span class="weee">(
                        <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                            <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        )</span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="highPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, false) ?>
                            <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                            <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="highPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax, false) ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(0, 1))): // including ?>
                <?php $weeeAmountToDisplay = $_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes : $_weeeTaxAmount ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="price"<?php endif;?>>
                     <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
                     <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                </span>

                <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // show description ?>
                    <span class="weee">(
                        <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                            : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount() : 0), true, true); ?>
                            <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        )</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="price"<?php endif;?>>
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true) ?>
                    <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
                <span class="regular-price"><?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?></span><br/>
                <?php $weeeAmountToDisplay = $_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes : $_weeeTaxAmount ?>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                       <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount() : 0), true, true); ?>
                        <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="regular-price"
                      id="product-price-weee-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="price"<?php endif;?>>
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
                    <p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="price"<?php endif;?>>
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?><p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, true) ?><p class="mrp"><?php echo "MRP"; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: search your code for `class="sell-price"` and add it in that <p> since it looks like it's not in view.phtml

Comment: sorry, i didt found the class "sell-price" . where actually i have to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this code from bottom (add it here)

```
<p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"<?php if($helperSettings->isShowOfferPrice($_product)):?> itemprop="lowPrice"<?php endif;?>>
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                    <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?><?php
    echo " Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") .  " Delivery ";

        ?></p>
                </span>
                </p>
```

Comment: almost done,  i want  Selling Price + Rs 10 Delivery in one line

Comment: then you have to add this in `price.phtml`. open template hint and you will find the your file to edit.

Comment: sorry, body is limited to 30000 charactars, so  i edited your answer and posted the part 2 of price.phtml code, 1st part i added in question

Comment: did you enable template hints? which file was that?

Comment: answer it kindly check and feedback me

Comment: when  added your code in price.phtml , home page is not displaying properly. have some css issue: http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ , before it was displaying like this : https://test.collagekingapp.com/

Comment: it have some unclosed tag i think that it is adding a problem check that it is not css issue.

Comment: i am extremely sorry. It was my mistake.

Comment: no problem it happen...